# Connect two SharePoint Online Sites

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365, bcs

I'm experiencing my first SharePoint Online 2013 project and now I would like to know how to connect two different Site Collections, to read data from each other.

- I have a Public Facing Website and a Team Site, in separate Site Collections.
- I would like to read and create items from the Public Facing Website in some Team Site's lists.

Have you ever tried something like that? Which are the possible options to accomplish this task?

If the suggestion are: External Content Types and BCS. How do I set up these features for a SharePoint Online as the target?

Thanks in advance.